Why we cant broadcast a dictionary in databricks , broadcast func needs a dataframe as an input
error message
trying to broadcast a dictionary but always getting an error
small_data = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
broadcasted_data = broadcast(small_data)`

Hi, as stated in error message, you need to use df not dictinoary, these are two completely different objects. U can make df out of this dictionary first
